# How do Futures and asynchronous code work in Dart?

Tags: dart, asynchronous, async-await

I know my question is poorly worded, but I'm struggling to understand Futures, as well as `async` and `await` operations, and feel like I don't even understand enough to pose the question! When I run this code:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  clickLink();
  sendGet();
  String r = await response();
  useResponseString(r);
  done();
}

void clickLink() => print('link clicked');

void sendGet() => print('sending get');

Future<String> response() async {
  print('awaiting response...');
  var time = Duration(seconds:2);
  await Future.delayed(time).then((v){
      print('got response');
      return 'responseString';
  });
  return 'error';
}

void useResponseString(String s) {
  print('using $s');
}

void done()=>print('done');
```

I get

> link clicked
> sending get
> awaiting response...

And then two seconds later

> got response
> using error
> done

When I go through this line by line, I don't understand why `response()` returns "error" rather than "responseString."

If I change the function to

```dart
Future<String> response() async {
  print('awaiting response...');
  var time = Duration(seconds:2);
  await Future.delayed(time).then((v){
      useResponseString('responseString);
      return 'responseString';
  });
  return 'error';
}
```

I get

> link clicked
> sending get
> awaiting response...

And then two seconds later

> using responseString
> using error
> done

The `.then()` function runs after 2 sec, calls `useResponseString` as I would expect (yay), but once again the main function's call to `useResponseString` returns with the value "error" rather than "responseString". What am I missing?

Comment: Your response function returns 'error' always, regardless of what your delayed future does/returns.

Comment: @Jeppe So the code execution doesn't get to the `await` line, wait two seconds, and then (if successful) return "responseString"--never getting to the next line?

Comment: What you return inside the Future determines what the result of awaiting it will be, not what is returned by the function around it. Then you should write `return await Future.delayed...`

Comment: Understood! ... If you write out your response I can accept it as the answer. (Thank you!)

Comment: Do not mix `.then()` and `async`/ `await`. The later was invented to ease the problems of the former, so don't shoot yourself in the foot. Drop `then` from your toolbelt, it offers nothing that async/await would not be able to do, yet it offers many many pitfalls, one of which you experienced just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the general misconception here is that returning a value from within a future will impact what is returned by the function containing the future. You could have multiple futures being awaited in a function - or you can await multiple futures at once even.

Lets zoom in on the future:

```
await Future.delayed(time).then((v){
      print('got response');
      return 'responseString';
});
```

What happens is that you set up a future which resolves after 2 seconds (`Future.delayed(time)`) and chain a callback (`.then((v){...})`) which produces another future that in your case returns `string`. This is all awaited but not saved anywhere. What you probably want is to store the result:

```
var result = await Future.delayed(time).then((v){
      print('got response');
      return 'responseString';
});
// result will have the value 'responseString'
```

Your function has only one return statement (`return 'error';`) and will always return that. Hope that clears it up. :-)